# CodeIgniter error- Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a very simple method that is meant to add validation rules from a form (if no ID, password is required otherwise not - New user vs update user).

```
public function edit($id = NULL){
  $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
  $id || $rules['password'] .= '|required';
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
  $this->load->view('_layout_admin_main',$this->data);
}
```

`$rules` is set in the model as (although I can't see how it's relevant):

```
public $rules = array(
        'name' => array(
                'field' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Name',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        ),
        'email' => array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email|xss_clean'
        ),
        'password' => array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_c]'
        ),
        'password_c' => array(
                'field' => 'password_c',
                'label' => 'Password Confirmation',
                'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
        ),
        'username' => array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'trim|is_unique|xss_clean|required'
        )
    );
```

The error is **Message: Array to string conversion ... Line Number: 27**, the `$id` reference is causing it specifically when `$id` is `NULL`. When `$id` is set, it is fine and dandy. `$id` is definitely not an array.

I know this is vague but this literally is it. Please ask questions if you have any ideas and I'll post any more that you need.

Comment: i think it is `$rules['password'] .= '|required';` which is causing the problem.
rules is an array where required is string. you are trying to concatanate string with array.
im not sure thou but i also wants to know if someone solved for you i will also love to know what was the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a small issue with the way you concatenate `required` to the rules, try this instead :

```
public function edit($id = NULL){
  $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
  $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required'; // issue was here
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
  $this->load->view('_layout_admin_main',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it was something that obvious. thanks @MaxiWheat!